# Python 3: Move email to trash by uid (imaplib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imaplib

I want to move an email from my inbox to the trash folder, I do not want the email permanently deleted, I want it to go through the process of waiting 30 days in the trash to be permanently deleted.

#### 1.Logged in:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login("example@gmail.com", "example")
```

#### 2.Got the list of uids in my inbox:

```
mail.select("inbox")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
uidList = data[0].split()
```

#### 3.Processed these emails:

```
#processEmails returns the uids of the emails that I need
#not really important for the purposes of this question

newUidList = processEmails(uidList)
```

#### 4.Delete the emails in the `newUidList`

```
for uid in newUidList:
    mail.uid('STORE',uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')
```

I thought that this line `mail.uid('STORE',uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')` would solve the problem (because that's what I found on the internet). But being here asking this question, you probably have correctly guessed that it did not.

#### What was happening?

When I executed this script, the emails disappeared from the inbox just as planned. But when I visit the trash folder, there is nothing there. So I thought maybe they were permanently deleted.

But they were not. I noticed this when I saw that my email storage space is filling up quick which means my emails were still there somewhere.

I go into the "All Emails" folder and there they are.

#### So my question is...

1. How do I get the result I want? Which is moving the emails to the trash folder by their UIDs.
2. Why is it not doing what I thought it would do? I am asking for an explanation for this line `mail.uid('STORE',uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')`

#### And most importantly...

Thank you for your input :)

Comment: You're supposed to move the emails to `IMAP/Trash` and not `\\Deleted` IIRC. Might be just `Trash`.

Comment: @Torxed I tried your suggestions: `mail.uid('STORE', uid, '+FLAGS', '(IMAP/Trash)')`, `mail.uid('STORE',b'249', '+FLAGS', '(Trash)')`. Also without the parentheses: `mail.uid('STORE', uid, '+FLAGS', 'IMAP/Trash')` and `mail.uid('STORE',b'249', '+FLAGS', 'Trash')`. They don't even get the email out of the inbox.

Comment: Try `[Gmail]/Trash`. If that doesn't work I'm ejecting myself from this problem. Haven't used the IMAP syntax in a long while and they do change it from decade to decade :P

Comment: @Torxed Unfortunately, it did not work. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I found the answer!

So for anyone having the same problem, I found out how to move your email to the trash by uid. referring back to my post, I should have put `mail.uid('STORE', uid, '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')` instead of `mail.uid('STORE',uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')`

And there you have it :)

Comment: So I was right, it was `Trash` instead of `Deleted`?

Comment: @Torxed You were right about the `Trash` part. But the part you forgot about was the `'+X-GM-LABELS'` instead of `'+FLAGS'`

Comment: Ah cool, yea as mentioned. Long time since I fiddled with this. Glad it works! Don't forget to mark your own answer as the solution so others can see what helped :D

Comment: @Torxed Will do as soon as the 24hrs have passed so I can be able to mark my own answer as "Accepted"

Comment: Can I use the same function to move emails to a different folder other than Tash ?